# canOpenURL failing for system-wide URL schemes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uiapplication

I'm running iOS 9b5.

In my app, if a device can make a phone call, I want to color the text blue so it looks tappable. If not, I leave it black.

In order to determine the device capabilities, I use:

```
[[UIApplcation sharedApplication] canOpenURL:@"telprompt://5555555555"]
```

As we all know, iOS 9 requires we whitelist any URL schemes we'll be using in our app as a privacy measure.

I have this in my Info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>  
<array>  
  <string>telprompt</string>  
</array>
```

No matter what I do, I still get canOpenURL: failed for URL: "telprompt://" - error: "(null)". I've tried tel:// and sms:// and I can't seem to avoid that syslog warning.

Does anybody know of a way to detect whether or not a device can make a phone call wtihout triggering these warnings?

Comment: Are you getting the "This app is not allowed to query for scheme" error?

Comment: Exactly. Seems like all schemes, even those included with iOS, need to be white listed, but the system doesn't respect the scheme when added to the whitelist.

Comment: I am also getting Exact same issue with iOS 9 beta 6

Comment: Did you try it on a real device or was this in a sim?

Answer (score 9):

What I discovered so far is, that if the console logs `-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "xxx://" - error: "(null)"`, it actually works. As soon as there is any other error than `null`, it may not work. If the error is `"This app is not allowed to query for scheme xxx"`, then you have to add this scheme to your app's .plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>xxx</string>
</array>
```

Strange behavior that the console output looks like an error although there is none, indeed.

Comment: Yes, the `"This app is not allowed..."` error is telling you to add the scheme to app's .plist file. If the error says `"(null)"`, however, this is an Apple bug (http://www.openradar.me/23022383) and shouldn't be appearing

Answer (score 8):

I think you might need to try this on an actual device, or just try it again. I just got this working on my iPhone 5, it looks like you don't even need to add it to the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. If the app is built with Xcode 7 Beta 6 and you use canOpenURL or openURL like below it seems to work just fine on device.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:555-555-5555"]]`

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:555-555-5555"]]`

On the iOS sim I still get the error:
**LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme tel

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "tel:555-555-5555" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme tel"**

Comment: That is because the simulator doesn't have the `tel` URL scheme. It seems that the error is logged to the console if the URL scheme is not present on the device

Comment: @jfeldman I wan't asking a question about why it doesn't work in the sim. Many things do not work in a Simulator which is why you test on a device. The original poster has still not confirmed if they tested on a device. I was providing the error so that others knew what it looked like.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error in IOS9 devices. So I have used below code snippet to avoid this error.

```
NSString *cleanedString = [[[PHONE NUMBER] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *escapedPhoneNumber = [cleanedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@", escapedPhoneNumber];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
}
```

Comment: This works for me and this is right answer. All developers should go with this code.No need to add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. Thanks, Anooj

Answer (score 2):

As iOS9 deprecates stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding, the following can be used to clean the telprompt: URL.

```
NSString *cleanedString = [[[PHONE NUMBER] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
//NSString *escapedPhoneNumber = [cleanedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *escapedPhoneNumber = [cleanedString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@", escapedPhoneNumber];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure, when to use `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` ? There're lots of other character sets available.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS9 I'm using this code and it works:

```
NSString *assistanceNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AssistanceCallMISDN"];
    assistanceNumber= [[assistanceNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    assistanceNumber = [assistanceNumber stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:assistanceNumber]];
    NSURL *phoneFallbackUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:assistanceNumber]];

    if ([UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:phoneUrl];
    } else if ([UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:phoneFallbackUrl]) {
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:phoneFallbackUrl];
    } else
    {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No se ha podido realizar la llamada a través de la aplicación. Puede llamar usted al %@", assistanceNumber] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        [_viewEmergency setHidden:YES];
    }
```

My Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>telprompt</string>
    <string>tel</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running this on a real device instead of simulator. No need to add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` for the `tel` scheme.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
NSString *phone_number = [[yourPhoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@", phone_number]]];
```