# canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instagram://app" - error: "(null)

Tags: swift, ios9, info.plist

I get this error:

***-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instagram://app" - error: "(null)"***

This is the code I use:

```
let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")!     
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL)) {
    //some code
}
```

I added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes to my info.plist file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>
```

And it seems to "recognise" the instagram scheme, cause when I use something else like "instagraam" I get a different error message (which makes sense):

***-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instagraam://app" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme instagraam"***

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: See the related questions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107315/canopenurl-failing-for-system-wide-url-schemes?rq=1

Comment: I even read that beforehand - just thought it would only apply to "telprompt". Thanks, it works on a real device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments - this is in fact a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107315/canopenurl-failing-for-system-wide-url-schemes?rq=1).

On a real device it works, it's just weird output of the simulator.