# Call number function error canOpenURL: failed for URL: "tel://0478733797" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme tel"

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting this error in the log?

Though I am running this on the simulator, will this matter in the testing stage?

> canOpenURL: failed for URL: "tel://0478733797" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme tel"
>   callNumber button pressed

Here is my function.

The string is "0478733797"

```
func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {
    if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)") {
        let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
        if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
            application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you added the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your .plist

Comment: In simulator this will not work, you need to test in device. simulator doens't have carrier service.

Comment: thanks Paul Marshal and Anbu.Karthik LSApplicationQueriesSchemes does not self populate in my .plist?

Comment: this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107315/canopenurl-failing-for-system-wide-url-schemes?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing describes that you have not allowed your app to open an query scheme. To solve that you should add following permission in your info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>tel</string>
    </array>
```

And run your application on the **Device** instead of **Simulator**

Answer (score 0):

To make a call to a number, you simply need to do this:

```
let urlSchema = "tel:"
let numberToCall = "0478733797"
if let numberToCallURL = URL(string: "\(urlSchema)\(numberToCall)")
{
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(numberToCallURL)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(numberToCallURL)
    }
}
```

Only the `URL` that you are creating using `tel:` is not in the correct format.

There is no need to add anything to the `Info.plist`. Also, call is not supported on an `iOS Simulator`. So try running it on an actual device.

Let me know if you still face any issues. Happy Coding..